# How to logout in Flutter using BLoC provider and redirect to login screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, retrofit

I am pretty new to the BLoC provider and this is the first bigger project where I implement the provider. To give you a short overview of the project, it has a login screen, after successfully logging in - it redirects you to the 'Reservations' screen where you can view all your reservations.

I am using retrofit for the API calls, the authentication is made with Password Grant type (OAuth), meaning it returns access and refresh token when the login details are correct.

I implemented an interceptor so when the access token is expired, it fires a new API call to the /oauth/refresh with the refreshToken from storage in order to obtain a new access and refresh tokens.

What I want to achieve is the following scenario: if the access token is expired, then it tries to obtain new one by passing the refresh token, however if that is expired too then it return an error (401 Unauthenticated) - if this scenario happens I would like to logout the user from the app and redirect them to the /login screen.

I have implemented it, it successfully removes the user from the secure storage, however, the screen is stuck on the 'Reservations' screen with circular progress indicator loading, rather than navigating to the login screen.

Here's a code breakdown:

These are my three screens.
main.dart

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeDependencies();
  runApp(MyApp(
    appRouter: AppRouter(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppRouter appRouter;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.appRouter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(430, 932),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
                create: (context) =>
                    sl<AuthBloc>()..add(const CheckAuthentication()),
              ),
              BlocProvider<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(
                create: (context) => sl<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(),
              ),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(),
              home: BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                  if (state is Authenticated) {
                    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/reservations', (route) => false);
                  } else if (state is Unauthenticated) {
                    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (route) => false);
                  }
                },
                child: Navigator(
                  key: navigatorKey,
                  onGenerateRoute: AppRouter().onGenerateRoute,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _usernameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _usernameFocusNode.dispose();
    _passwordFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: colorGrayLighter,
        body: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoadingState) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top + 0.1.sh),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/logo.png',
                            height: 0.06.sh,
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.07.sh),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFieldWidget(
                                  textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                                  defaultText: 'Корисничко име',
                                  hintText: 'Корисничко име',
                                  focusNode: _usernameFocusNode,
                                  controller: _usernameController,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.sp,
                                ),
                                TextFieldWidget(
                                  textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                                  defaultText: 'Лозинка',
                                  hintText: 'Лозинка',
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                                  controller: _passwordController,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30.sp,
                      ),
                      CommonButton(
                        buttonText: 'Најави се',
                        buttonType: ButtonType.FilledRed,
                        onTap: () {
                          BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(LoginEvent(
                              LoginDto(
                                  username: _usernameController.text,
                                  password: _passwordController.text)));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

reservations.dart

```
class ReservationsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReservationsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReservationsScreen> createState() => _ReservationsScreenState();
}

class _ReservationsScreenState extends State<ReservationsScreen> {
  void showAlert(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Error"),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text("OK"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    BlocProvider.of<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(context)
        .add(const GetReservationsFindAll());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: colorGrayLighter,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .viewPadding
                  .top,
            ),
            Text("Резервации", style: font28Medium),
            Container(
              height: 40.h,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(context)
                                .add(GetReservationsFindAll(
                                reservationsFindAllDto:
                                ReservationsFindAllDto(
                                    filterReservationsEnum:
                                    FilterReservationsEnum.ALL)));
                          },
                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                                color: colorBlack), // Set border color
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Сите (1029)',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: colorBlack,
                                )),
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(context)
                                .add(GetReservationsFindAll(
                                reservationsFindAllDto:
                                ReservationsFindAllDto(
                                    filterReservationsEnum:
                                    FilterReservationsEnum
                                        .NOT_APPROVED)));
                          },
                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: Size.zero,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                                color: colorGrayLight), // Set border color
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Непотврдени (1029)',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: colorGrayLight,
                                )),
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<ReservationsFindAllBloc>(context)
                                .add(GetReservationsFindAll(
                                reservationsFindAllDto:
                                ReservationsFindAllDto(
                                    filterReservationsEnum:
                                    FilterReservationsEnum
                                        .APPROVED)));
                          },
                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: Size.zero,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                                color: colorGrayLight), // Set border color
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Потврдени (1029)',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: colorGrayLight,
                                )),
                          ))),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Other widgets...
            Expanded(
              child: BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                  if (state is Unauthenticated) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
                  }
                },
                child: BlocBuilder<ReservationsFindAllBloc,
                    ReservationsFindAllState>(
                  builder: (_, state) {
                    if (state is ReservationsLoading) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }

                    if (state is ReservationsLoaded) {
                      return ReservationsList(
                        reservationListEntity: state.reservationListEntity!,
                      );
                    }

                    if (state is ReservationsError) {
                      Future.microtask(() {
                        showAlert(Utils.getErrorResponseMessage(
                            state.exception!.response!));
                      });
                    }

                    return const SizedBox();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

These are the Blocs:
reservations_find_all_bloc.dart

```
class ReservationsFindAllBloc extends Bloc<ReservationsFindAllEvent, ReservationsFindAllState> {
  final FindAllUseCase _findAllUseCase;

  ReservationsFindAllBloc(this._findAllUseCase) : super(const ReservationsLoading()) {
    on<GetReservationsFindAll>(onFindAll);
  }

  void onFindAll(GetReservationsFindAll getReservationsFindAll, Emitter<ReservationsFindAllState> emit) async {
    emit(const ReservationsLoading());

    final dataState = await _findAllUseCase.call(params: getReservationsFindAll.reservationsFindAllDto);

    if (dataState is DataSuccess) {
      emit(ReservationsLoaded(dataState.data!));
    }

    if (dataState is DataFailed) {
      emit(ReservationsError(dataState.exception!));
    }
  }
}
```

auth_bloc.dart

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final LoginUseCase _loginUseCase;
  final LogoutUseCase _logoutUseCase;
  final SecureStorage _secureStorage;

  AuthBloc(this._loginUseCase, this._logoutUseCase, this._secureStorage)
      : super(const Unauthenticated()) {
    on<LoginEvent>(onLogin);
    on<LogoutEvent>(onLogout);
    on<CheckAuthentication>(onCheckAuthentication);
  }

  void onLogin(LoginEvent loginEvent, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    emit(const LoadingState());
    final dataState = await _loginUseCase(params: loginEvent.loginDto);

    if (dataState is DataSuccess) {
      emit(Authenticated(dataState.data!));
    }

    if (dataState is DataFailed) {
      emit(AuthenticationError(dataState.exception!));
    }
  }

  void onLogout(LogoutEvent logoutEvent, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    emit(const LoadingState());

    final isLoggedOut = await _logoutUseCase.call();

    if (isLoggedOut) {
      emit(const Unauthenticated());
    }
  }

  void onCheckAuthentication(CheckAuthentication checkAuthentication,
      Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    final user = await _secureStorage.getUser();

    if (user != null) {
      emit(Authenticated(user));
    } else {
      emit(const Unauthenticated());
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the interceptor:

If the follow statement is true `else if (response is DataFailed)` then the user should be logged out and taken to the /login screen.

auth_interceptor.dart

```
class AuthInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final TokenRepository _tokenRepository;
  final SecureStorage _secureStorage;
  final AuthBloc authBloc;
  final _dio = sl<Dio>();

  AuthInterceptor(this._secureStorage, this._tokenRepository, this.authBloc);

  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print('Data for request...');
    print(options.data);
    options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    if (options.headers.containsKey('Content-Type')) {
      options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    if (!options.extra.containsKey('isRetry')) {
      final accessToken = await _secureStorage.getAccessToken();

      if (accessToken != null) {
        options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
      }
    }

    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 &&
        err.response?.data['error'] == 'Token expired.') {
      try {
        final refreshToken = await _secureStorage.getRefreshToken();

        if (refreshToken != null) {
          final response = await _tokenRepository.refresh(
            RefreshTokenDto(refreshToken: refreshToken),
          );

          if (response is DataSuccess) {
            // Retry the original request with new access token
            final RequestOptions retryOptions = err.requestOptions;
            retryOptions.extra['isRetry'] = true; // Set flag to indicate retry
            retryOptions.headers['Authorization'] =
                'Bearer ${response.data!.accessToken}';
            // Resend the request with updated options
            final updatedResponse = await _dio.request(
              retryOptions.uri.toString(),
              options: Options(
                method: retryOptions.method,
                headers: retryOptions.headers,
                responseType: retryOptions.responseType,
              ),
              data: retryOptions.data,
              queryParameters: retryOptions.queryParameters,
              cancelToken: retryOptions.cancelToken,
              onReceiveProgress: retryOptions.onReceiveProgress,
              onSendProgress: retryOptions.onSendProgress,
            );

            // Forward the response to the original handler
            return handler.resolve(updatedResponse);
          } else if (response is DataFailed) {
            // Logout user if refresh token fails
            authBloc.add(const LogoutEvent());
            return;
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error refreshing tokens: $e');
      }
      return handler.next(err);
    }

    super.onError(err, handler);
  }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if I have messed up somewhere with the Bloc Providers, Listeners, or Builders throughout the app because I am still new to this concept.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**
Solved the issue by changing the onError function in the interceptor like this:

```
@override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 &&
        err.response?.data['error'] == 'Token expired.') {

      final refreshToken = await _secureStorage.getRefreshToken();

      if (refreshToken != null) {
        final response = await _tokenRepository.refresh(
          RefreshTokenDto(refreshToken: refreshToken),
        );

        if (response is DataSuccess) {
          // Retry the original request with new access token
          final RequestOptions retryOptions = err.requestOptions;
          retryOptions.extra['isRetry'] = true; // Set flag to indicate retry
          retryOptions.headers['Authorization'] =
              'Bearer ${response.data!.accessToken}';
          // Resend the request with updated options
          final updatedResponse = await _dio.request(
            retryOptions.uri.toString(),
            options: Options(
              method: retryOptions.method,
              headers: retryOptions.headers,
              responseType: retryOptions.responseType,
            ),
            data: retryOptions.data,
            queryParameters: retryOptions.queryParameters,
            cancelToken: retryOptions.cancelToken,
            onReceiveProgress: retryOptions.onReceiveProgress,
            onSendProgress: retryOptions.onSendProgress,
          );

          // Forward the response to the original handler
          return handler.resolve(updatedResponse);
        } else if (response is DataFailed) {
          final RequestOptions retryOptions = response.exception != null
              ? response.exception!.requestOptions
              : RequestOptions();
          retryOptions.extra['isLogout'] = true; // Set flag to indicate log out

          DioException exception = DioException(
            error: 'Token refresh failed',
            requestOptions: retryOptions,
            response: response.exception!.response,
            type: DioExceptionType.badResponse,
          );

          return handler.next(exception);
        }
      }

      return handler.next(err);
    }

    super.onError(err, handler);
  }
```

This way it passes an extra 'isLogout' when the refresh token fails and throws an exception, then in reservations.dart handled the error state like below:

```
if (state is ReservationsError) {
                    if (state.exception != null) {
                      if (state.exception!.requestOptions.extra
                          .containsKey('isLogout')) {
                        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context)
                            .add(const LogoutEvent());
                      } else if (state.exception?.response != null) {
                        Future.microtask(() {
                          showAlert(Utils.getErrorResponseMessage(
                              state.exception!.response!));
                        });
                      }
                    } else {
                      Future.microtask(() {
                        showAlert(Utils.getErrorResponseMessage(null));
                      });
                    }
                  }
```

and finally in main.dart the listener should be like this - manually reset the state of the bloc:

```
listener: (context, state) {
                  if (state is Authenticated) {
                    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                        '/reservations', (route) => false);
                  } else if (state is Unauthenticated) {
                    //Reset the state of the blocs to its initial state
                    (context.read<ReservationsFindAllBloc>())
                        .reset(const ReservationsLoading());

                    navigatorKey.currentState!
                        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (route) => false);
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can logout as:

```
void onLogout(LogoutEvent logoutEvent, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
  emit(const LoadingState());

  final isLoggedOut = await _logoutUseCase.call();

  if (isLoggedOut) {
    emit(const Unauthenticated());
  }
}
```

and you need to properly handle `Unauthenticated` state

```
    if (state is Unauthenticated) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');

        //or

        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
        (route) => false,
      );
     }
```

Comment: Yeah the logout is now working as it should. I fixed it by changing the interceptor onError so if the refresh token fails it would throw a DioException and then handle that in reservations screen if it has extra param 'isLogout' in the response I navigate to the Logout using this BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context)                          .add(const LogoutEvent()); 

The issue I experience now is that after logout from here, the state of the Reservation block is stuck on ReservationsError state rather than being reset. How can I reset the state of the blocs on logout?

Comment: So if your problem is solved, it is better to accept the answer as it can help the community.
Moreover, if you want to close the bloc, it's how bloc documentation says
"In most cases, BlocProvider should be used to create new blocs which will be made available to the rest of the subtree. In this case, since BlocProvider is responsible for creating the bloc, it will automatically handle closing the bloc.

In some cases, BlocProvider can be used to provide an existing bloc to a new portion of the widget tree."

Comment: The answer did not helps solving the problem, also in this case the bloc had to be closed manually

Comment: Can't you logout and redirect to login screen?

Comment: updated the question with the working version